# Python Can't Import Class From Parent Directory?

Tags: python, import, dry, modularity

I am new to Python, so I might not be seeing the obvious solution to this. I have searched online for a solution and everyone seems to have the same answer. I am trying to import a file from a parent directory in Python. I am coming from JavaScript where you simply type `import Function from '../ParenetDirectory/FileThatIncludesFunction'` and you can import that module. Every website I have visited says you have to include the parent directory in your freakin' `path` to import it. Are we serious here? I assume I am missing something because it seems to me that Python would have a more elegant way to do this than editing your freaking `path` to import a class from a parent directory. Please tell me it does, or explain to me why it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the sys module and adding the desired directory to its path.

`"../ParenetDirectory/FileThatIncludesFunction.py"` :

```py
def Function():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

`main.py` :

```py
import sys

sys.path.append('../ParenetDirectory')

from FileThatIncludesFunction import Function

print(Function())
```

**Note that if you want to run this via cmd, make sure that the folder in cmd is exactly where the main.py file is located.**

Comment: Thank you @ThisIsMatin. That does work as you describe. It feels very clunky as I mentioned, but that appears to be the way to do it in Python.